# GridView adding ExtensionData column

Tags: wpf, gridview, soap

After pushing the button in the form, my custom SOAP service is ran:

```
 private void btnSoapClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs s)
 {
            ServiceReference1.ServiceClient ProxySOAP = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
            ProdSOAP.ItemsSource = ProxySOAP.GetProducts();
 }
```

Where GetProduct method returns an array of Products:

```
[DataContract]
public class Product
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ProdNo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string MadeOf { get; set; }
}
```

And finally the data is stored in GridView. Some additional column called ExtensionData is added:

[image]

Where does it come from and how to get rid of it? Please let me know if any additional portion of code is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. During adding the reference to the service in other project some additional code was auto-generated:

```
[global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {
        get {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }
```

And as a result created additional field in my Product class.